# Pandas to csv without string quotes and with out list box

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

i am using this dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/carrie1/ecommerce-data

And i have below code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", delimiter=",", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
data_combined = data.groupby('InvoiceNo').agg(lambda x: x.tolist())
```

When i try to use data_combined["Description"].to_csv(), i got below example:

```
['WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER', 'WHITE METAL LANTERN', 'CREAM CUPID HEARTS COAT HANGER',...]
```

My question is how can i export data_combined["Description"] to a .csv file with below format:

```
WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER,WHITE METAL LANTERN,CREAM CUPID HEARTS COAT HANGER,...
```

with out string quotes and list box.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Do you need all `Description` values as a single line?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i need every rows in Description column, sir.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply printing the string representation of the csv data, ready to be printed in the csv file. If you need just a string representation of that data you can just do

```py
print(data_combined[“Description”].to_csv().join(‘,’))
```

Comment: Please i don’t know how to use code syntax, some mod could help me? I’m on monile browser

Answer (score 0):

Try add filename:

```
data_combined["Description"].to_csv('some_file.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new dataframe out of the `Description` series while reinstating the list. It will iterpret the list items as separate columns:

`pd.DataFrame(data_combined['Description'].tolist()).to_csv()`